# Unable to make NSURL form string

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsstring, nsurl

I'm trying to read a a file in my project. I first create a string with the path and then turn it into a NSURL, and that's where I get into trouble:

```
NSString *sndPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vader" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sndPath]; //url is nil!
```

The contents of sndPath is:

> /Users/fernando/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/4B677E62-A6BB-4436-A3DA-EB83A57917FF/Ex1.app/vader.caf

The file does exist, BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a URL that represents a file system path, you should use

```
+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]
```

or

```
+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]
```